# Why doesn't Apache Oltu Instragram integration return access_token

Tags: java, spring-mvc, instagram, oltu

I am developing a Spring MVC + Apache Oltu + Instagram example. In this example I created an App on **https://www.instagram.com/developer/** and I got the `ClientId` and `Client_Secrete`.

Uisng this `clientId` and `Client Secret`, calling the **Instagram Rest EndPoints**. But when calling either the REST EndPoint I am getting the below error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/apache-oltu] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Missing parameters: access_token', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}] with root cause
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Missing parameters: access_token', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleOAuthProblemException(OAuthUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleMissingParameters(OAuthUtils.java:185)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateRequiredParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:90)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:49)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:127)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:96)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:60)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:120)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at com.apache.oltu.InstagramController.getAccessToken(InstagramController.java:76)
    at com.apache.oltu.InstagramController.redirect(InstagramController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Following are the details I used:**

```
AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize";
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
```

The scopes which I used are:

```
public_content follower_list comments relationships likes basic
```

When code is executing, I am getting the authorizationCode successfully, but looks like token is missing.

I am calling the Rest Endpoint from URL: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

The code which I used below for reference:

```
private String getAccessToken(String authorizationCode) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .tokenLocation(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
                .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URL)
                .setCode(authorizationCode)
                .buildQueryMessage();

        OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());

        GitHubTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, GitHubTokenResponse.class);

        request= new OAuthBearerClientRequest("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/").
                setAccessToken(oAuthResponse.getAccessToken()).
                buildQueryMessage();

        System.out.println("REQUEST_BODY : "+request.getBody());

        OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
        OAuthResourceResponse resourceResponse= client.resource(request, "GET", OAuthResourceResponse.class);

        if (resourceResponse.getResponseCode()==200){           
            logger.debug("HTTP OK");
            System.out.println(resourceResponse.getBody());
            return resourceResponse.getBody();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Could not access resource: " + resourceResponse.getResponseCode() 
            + " " + resourceResponse.getBody());
            return null;
        }
    } 
}
```

The following is the URL which is going ::

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?
>   scope=public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes+basic&
>   response_type=code&
>   redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapache-oltu%2Finstagram%2Fredirect&
>   client_id=40eb3e6047a249ddb7d9194765be9901

If I used ResponseType="token" then I get the

```
{"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403, "error_message": "Implicit authentication is disabled"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error method, I was able to resolve this issue:

While making request for the access token I should be using the below:

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URL)
                .setResponseType(ResponseType.CODE.toString())
                .setScope("public_content follower_list comments relationships likes basic")
                .buildQueryMessage();
```

and with the subsequent request I will be using the below:

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                //.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.INSTAGRAM)
                .tokenLocation(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
                .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URL)
                .setCode(authorizationCode)
                .buildBodyMessage();
```

and this gives me the solid Response:

```
{"data": {"id": "3159574895", "username": "Raj", "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19367511_329283184160313_6318737005198966784_a.jpg", "full_name": "Raj", "bio": "Wish me on 25th-Dec\nLove to code !! \nEngineer by my choice !!\nLove to drive !! \ud83d\ude0b\ud83d\ude0a", "website": "", "is_business": false, "counts": {"media": 14, "follows": 18, "followed_by": 51}}, "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

After more google found : **[OAuthProblem, missing parameter access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212708/oauthproblem-missing-parameter-access-token)**